# Sending QueryDict object from Javascript (without form?)

Tags: javascript, django

How can i send information from Javascript to a Django view in a QueryDict object without using forms?

For example, this is my dictionary in JS:

```
const postDict = {
    'request_name':'change-extra-fields',
    'type': 'increase',
    'id': droppedElId,
}
```

And this is my view (and expected result of print)

```
class ExampleView(View):
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST['request_name'] == 'edit-main-fields':
            task.update_from_request(**request.POST)
        elif request.POST['request_name'] == 'change-extra-fields':
            print(request.POST)
```

`<QueryDict: {'request_name': ['change-extra-fields'], 'type': ['increase'], 'id': ['6'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['0NHXB1Nn4uimjNXARjq9wfVdCLjVFcBBDTiGIBHt4Mjcqu3YPx5vqFLJvHT4ra3b']}>`

My current solution is to make a form element with every piece of information and submit.. However, i'm not sure if there's a faster / more correct way of doing this

**Current solution:**

```
const sendCustomForm = function (valuesDict) {
    const ghostForm = document.createElement('form')
    ghostForm.method = 'POST'
    ghostForm.action = document.location.pathname

    valuesDict['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = csrftoken
    Object.keys(valuesDict).forEach(key => {
        const newInput = document.createElement('input')
        newInput.setAttribute('name', key)
        newInput.setAttribute('value', valuesDict[key])

        ghostForm.appendChild(newInput)
    })

    document.body.appendChild(ghostForm)
    ghostForm.submit()
}

sendCustomForm(postDict)
```

This solution works but i'm not sure if that's the most correct.
Recently i asked for help on how to setup JSON post-requests with Javascript but i kind of need to have the information on a QueryDict, otherwise the if-condition on my post view will fail.

Comment: You can make a POST request with jQuery for example: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem There's no `jquery` tag nor any jQuery in the question. And you don't need jQuery to make a post request...

Comment: @Andreas: of course you can make a POST request without jQuery, why is this ad hominem argument relevant?

Comment: Hmm ok that works surprisingly well! Please post as an answer so i can validate. Btw, yes i didn't intend to ask for a JQuery solution in the beginning but i don't really care right now since jquery is really smooth to use. It would be nice to know how to do it in pure JS though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send dict to views like this

```
    $("button").click(function(){
  $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
  {
    name: "Donald Duck",
    city: "Duckburg"
  },
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```